# showing $G_3$ in lower central series is trivial for a particular group $G$

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group generated by three elements a, b, c, such that their squares are trivial, i.e. $a^2 = b^2 = c^2 = 1$, and the squares of their commutators are also trivial, i.e., $[a, b]^2 = [a, c]^2 = [b, c]^2 = 1$.  Assume also that the following elements in $G_3$ of the lower central series are also trivial: $[[a, b], c] = 1$ and $[[a, c], b] = 1$.  Then show that $G_3 = 1$.

It is easy to show that all elements of $G_3$ are trivial with the exception of the element $[[a, c], b]$ (or equivalently $[[c, a], b]$.  So my question boils down to showing that this element is trivial, which then implies that the group is of order 64 and is actually Group 144 in the book by Hall & Senior on the groups of order $2^n$ for n less than or equal to 6.  Another way of thinking of the problem is to show that $G$ is metabelian, i.e. that the commutator subgroup $G'$ is abelian, as then we could use commutator relations and the Witt Identity to show that this element is trivial.

Comment: Is there a typo? You mention assuming $[[a,c],b]=1$, but then say you cannot show it is trivial? Anyway, dpes the Hall-Witt identity not help?

Comment: But you assumed that $[a,c],b]=1$.

Comment: It follows from the Hall-Witt identity that $[[
b,c],a]=1$.

Answer (score 1):

One form of the Hall-Witt identity (see [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Group_theory))  is $$[[x,y^{-1}],z]^y[[y,z^{-1}],x]^z[[z,x^{-1}],y]^x=1.$$
Since $a^2=b^2=c^2=1$, it follows that $[[a,b],c]=1$ and $[[a,c],b]=1$ imply $[[b,c],a]=1$.

Since the group defined by the presentation $\langle a,b \mid a^2=b^2=[a,b]^2=1 \rangle$ is dihedral of order $8$ with $[a,b]$ in the centre, we have $[[a,b],a] = [[a,b],b]=1$ and since $[[a,b],c]=1$, $[a,b]$ commutes with all generators of $G$ and hence $[a,b] \in Z(G)$. Similarly $[a,c],[b,c] \in Z(G)$.

Now the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ of $G$ is the normal closure of the subgroup generated by the commutators of the generators, and since $Z(G)$ is normal in $G$, we have $[G,G] \le Z(G)$ and hence $G_3=1$.

The group defined by this presentation is $\mathtt{SmallGroup}(64,73)$ in the small groups database, which is probably better known than the Hall-Senior tables nowadays.